# Help finding a 10 parameter equivalent to a 5 parameter fitting function?

Tags: functions

This is my first question posted here.
I apologize if this post is misformatted or inappropriate in any way.

I have a relatively simple fitting function f(m):

$$f(m) = {1\over\sqrt{{A\over M_1} + {BV_1\over m}}} + C$$ 
where $A, B, C, M_1$ and $ V_1 $ are known fitting parameters for a particular data set.

And I have a relatively more complex (5 term) fitting function with 10 parameters:

$$f(m) = {(\frac {L_b} {2} -Z_0)\over\left({\left(\sqrt{C_v\frac {K_p}{M_2}} + \sqrt{C_v{K_p{m\over M_2}+{V_b\over2}-Z_0{V_b\over L_b}\over m}}\right)\over2}\right)} + {L_g\over \sqrt{C_v{K_p{m\over M_2}+{V_b\over2}-Z_0{V_b\over L_b}\over m}}} + {L_d\over \left({\sqrt{C_v{K_p{m\over M_2}+{V_b\over2}-Z_0{V_b\over L_b}\over m}}+\sqrt{C_v{K_p{m\over M_2}+{V_b\over2}-Z_0{V_b\over L_b}+V_2\over m}}\over 2}\right)} + {L_a\over \sqrt{C_v{K_p{m\over M_2}+{V_b\over2}-Z_0{V_b\over L_b}+V_2\over m}}} - T_0$$
where $C_v$ is a constant, and  $L_b, L_g, L_d, L_a, K_p, V_b, Z_0, T_0, M_2$ and $ V_2 $ are unknown fitting parameters.

Is it possible to find a set of 10 parameters that make the 2nd function equivalent to the 1st?

(It would be ideal if $M_1 = M_2$, and $V_1 = V_2$, but that is not a requirement.)

I do not have the skill to solve this, or even to guess whether it is solvable?

I realize this is not a problem of relevance to anyone but me, and I would understand completely if the community should decide to reject it.

Thank you in advance for your attention.

-RicoRico

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that meets your ideal condition:

$(T_0=-C,L_a=1,Z_0=1,L_b=2,L_g=0,L_d=0,C_v=B,K_p=\frac{A}{B},M_2=M_1,V_2=V_1)$

I don't know of a general method, but found this by inspection.  I noticed that the last two terms looked like they had everything you wanted, picked parameters that made all the other terms vanish, then solved for the remaining parameters.

Comment: Thank you! --  i think it took me 200 times longer to pose the question than it did for you to answer it, ha

Comment: No problem!  What was this for out of curiosity?